# oh-my-fish `omf: command not found` in WebStorm terminal emulator

Tags: webstorm, fish, fedora-25, oh-my-fish

I am using WebStorm 2017.1.3 on Fedora 25.

I have `fish` set up as my default shell and installed `oh-my-fish` so in 
Terminal I see my git branch and other information by default. `omf update` runs as expected.

In the WebStorm terminal emulator I still get fish, but not `omf`:

```
user@host ~> omf
fish: omf: command not found...
```

I'm a noob `fish` and `omf` user, can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: related issues: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169111, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173259

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer was given here: [IntelliJ's embedded terminal does not load fish functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609023/intellijs-embedded-terminal-does-not-load-fish-functions). I.e, add some lines of code to the app for the time being (until Jetbrains makes a fix).

Comment: This solution is easier than the originally accepted answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> I have fish set up as my default shell and installed oh-my-fish so in Terminal I see my git branch and other information by default.

Note that you don't need omf for this. Fish ships a number of prompts that include vcs information. You can pick one with `fish_config` or add the `__fish_vcs_prompt` function to your `fish_prompt`.

> In the WebStorm terminal emulator I still get fish, but not omf:
>
> user@host ~> omf
>
> fish: omf: command not found...

The "omf" function is stored in a file named "omf.fish" in a directory in $fish_function_path. This means that directory isn't included there.

The way omf works in a reasonably current (> 2.3.0) fish is that it has a bootstrap file (~/.config/fish/conf.d/omf.fish) that then sources the rest. It seems this isn't run.

I'd suggest you compare the values of $fish_function_path, $OMF_PATH and possibly $XDG_DATA_HOME in webstorm and outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, will get back to you once back in the office.

Comment: As you suggested $fish_function_path was set to a different value (apparently WebStorm looks for `~/.config/fish/config.fish` and loads that only, and I did not have that file. I created it with the content of
    . ~/.config/fish/conf.d/omf.fish
and now I have the same settings as outside of Webstorm

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by going to Settings | Terminal then turning off Shell integration.

This allowed me to run `omf` and also have the bobthefish theme work with powerline/nerd fonts (after updating the terminal font at Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Font Console)

I was using phpStorm 2017.3.4 but I assume this will also work in any IntelliJ embedded terminal.