# IntelliJ's embedded terminal does not load fish functions

Tags: intellij-idea, fish

I'm using IntelliJ's embedded terminal with the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/), which works well with one exception: it does not seem to load the fish functions defined in `~/.config/fish/functions/*`.

When I use the macOS Terminal.app or iTerm2, the functions get loaded as they are supposed to, only IntelliJ's embedded terminal fails to do so.

Oddly enough, the IntelliJ terminal *does* load `~/.config/fish/config.fish` just fine.

Here's the output of `echo $fish_function_path` in iterm2 and Terminal.app:

```
/Users/moritz/.config/fish/functions
/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.6.0/etc/fish/functions
/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_functions.d
/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.6.0/share/fish/functions
```

And here's the output when running the same in IntelliJ's embedded terminal:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/fish/functions
/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.6.0/etc/fish/functions
/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_functions.d
/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.6.0/share/fish/functions
```

I guess this looks like IntelliJ's embedded terminal initializes the fish session with a different value for `$fish_function_path`?

`$HOME` (=`/Users/moritz`) and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (not set) are the same in all three, iTerm2, Terminal.app and IntelliJ's embedded terminal.

Comment: Please follow this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173259 for updates.

Comment: Insufficient, and contradictory, information :-) If fish is able to find config.fish it should have no difficulty autoloading functions from your personal functions directory. When running fish inside IntelliJ what is $HOME and $XDG_CONFIG_HOME set to? Assuming the former is set but not the latter what does "ls -ld $HOME/.config/fish/functions" output? What is $fish_function_path set to? If you create a trivial autoloaded function, say "function ij; echo ij ran; end" in $HOME.config/fish/functions/ij.fish can you run that function by just typing "ij"?

Comment: What does `echo $fish_function_path` show? Is there a difference between its output under IntellJ's terminal vs Terminal.app?

Comment: Hi Kurtis Rader, I can run that function in iTerm2 and Terminal.app, but not in IntelliJ's embedded terminal. The aliases I defined in `config.fish` work even in IntelliJ's embedded terminal, though. Sorry if that's contradictory, but it is how it is ;-)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I was able to get the same result from `echo $fish_function_path` in IntelliJ's embeded terminal and iTerm2 by going to Settings | Terminal then turning off Shell integration.

I was using phpStorm 2017.3.4 but I assume this will also work in any IntelliJ embedded terminal.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that actually seems to work! Much easier solution than mine. Thanks! I'll accept this one and I think you could safely remove the last precautionary statement in your answer, if you like.

Comment: Although, I wonder what exactly that "Shell integration" is about anyway and what side effects it could have to turn it off...?

Comment: Not sure exactly what the Shell Integration does, but it is documented here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-terminal.html. I found the `fish.config` file that IntelliJ use, and decided I could live without :-)

Answer (score 37):

Check the intelliJ option. Turn off ***shell integration***.

[image]

Comment: I had a slightly different problem: My Fish prompt wasn't been displayed on Webstorm's terminal. I disabled this `Shell integration` option and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Someone posted a good solution for this in the [IntelliJ bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173259).

IntelliJ has its own `config.fish`, where `.config/fish/config.fish` does get loaded, but not the functions...

Add the following to IntelliJ's internal `config.fish` and the fish functions get loaded fine in IntelliJ's embedded terminal:

```
if test -d ~/.config/fish/functions
  for f in ~/.config/fish/functions/*.fish
    source $f
  end
end
```

The location of IntelliJ's `config.fish` varies, on macOS it could be

- Ultimate Edition: `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/fish/config.fish`
- Community Edition: `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/fish/config.fish`
- Or even something like this, if installed via Jetbrains Toolbox: `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/172.4574.11/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/fish`

You could also just replace that whole `fish` directory in IntelliJ's `plugins/terminal` with a symlink to your normal fish config directory, usually `.config/fish/`.

There's still another option: you can just link the `functions` directory, for example:

```
ln -s ~/.config/fish/functions \
  /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/fish/config.fish
```

Comment: I found a much easier way, just delete IDEA's fish directory and create a soft link to user's.

Comment: That's a good approach, too, although somewhat more invasive as it also overrides that `fishd.<something>` file that is also there which doesn't work very well with my setup for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

For me since since i use [`bass`](https://github.com/edc/bass) which also put some `.py` file in that directory, I have to tweak this a tad.

```
if test -d ~/.config/fish/functions
  for f in ~/.config/fish/functions/*.fish
    source $f
  end
end
```

Also I found the Ultimate Edition's path is a bit different: 
`/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/terminal/fish/config.fish`

Answer (score 0):

I still have the same problem in IntelliJ 2018.1 and also in Clion 2018.1. I tried to fix in Clion by suggestions in this thread, but someway it did not worked (I got even more error messages even if all seemed to be OK).

So my workaround solution is to set Idea terminal to /bin/bash (in Settings/Tools/Terminal - Shell Path), then as first command in terminal window enter fish.. and everything works fine, no fiddling with terminal plugin is needed.

(I find it quite a pity, that Jetbrain can't/doesn't want to fix it.. and /IDEA-173259 is "closed")

Comment: Have you tried just turning off the "shell integration" and leaving everything else as is?

Comment: what you mean by turning off the terminal integration? i do want to have the terminal window in intellij/clion..

Comment: It’s „shell integration“. Have a look at the accepted answer